# How to get SQL executed or transaction history on a Table (AS400) DB2 for IBM i

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have an issue in our database(AS400- DB2) in one of our tables all the rows were deleted. I do not know if it was a program or SQL that a user executed. All I know it hapend +- 3am in the morning. I did check for any scheduled jobs at that time.

We managed to get the data back from backups but I want to investigate what deleted the records or what user.

Are there any logs on die as400 on physical tables to check what SQL executed and when on a specified table? This will help me determine what caused this.

I tried checking I systems navigator but could not find any logs... Is there a way of getting transnational data on a table using i system navigator or green screen? And If I can get the SQL that executed in the timeline.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: probably more appropriate on Server Fault...

Comment: Best would be to refer to the journal for the table. It wouldn't matter if it was SQL or native I/O, everything is logged in the journal. If no journal is used, the system assumes it's not important to track.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.. I will create a journal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no mention of how the time was inferred\determined, but for lack of journaling, I would suggest a good approach is immediately to gather information about the file and member; DSPOBJD for both *SERVICE and *FULL, DSPFD for *ALL, DMPOBJ, and perhaps even a copy of the row for the TABLE from the catalog [to include the LAST_ALTERED_TIMESTAMP for ALTEREDTS column of SYSTABLES or the based-on field DBXATS from the QADBXREF].  Gathering those, worthwhile almost only if done before any other activity [esp. before any recovery activity], can help establish the time of the event and perhaps allude to what was the event; most timestamps are reflective of only of the most recent activity against the object [rather than as a historical log], so any recovery activity is likely to effect loss of any timestamps that would be reflective of the prior event\activity.

Even if there was no journal for the file and nothing in the plan cache, there may have been [albeit unlikely] an active SQL Monitor.  An active monitor should be available visible somewhere in the iNav GUI as well.  I am not sure of the visibility of a monitor that may have been active in a prior time-frame.

Similarly despite lack of journaling, there may be some system-level object or user auditing in effect for which the event was tracked either as a command-string or as an action on the file.member; combined with the inferred timing, all audit records spanning just before until just after can be reviewed.

Although there may have been nothing in the scheduled jobs, the History Log (DSPLOG) since that time may show jobs that ended, or [perhaps soon] prior to that time show jobs that started, which are more likely to have been responsible.  In my experience, often the name of the job may be indicative; for example the name of the job as the name of the file, perhaps due only to the request having been submitted from PDM.  Any spooled [or otherwise still available] joblogs could be reviewed for possible reference to the file and\or member name; perhaps a completion message for a CLRPFM request.

If the action may have been from a program, the file may be recorded as a reference-object such that output from DSPPGMREF may reveal programs with the reference, and any [service] program that is an SQL program could have their embedded SQL statements revealed with PRTSQLINF; the last-used for those programs could be reviewed for possible matches.  Note: module and program sources can also be searched, but there is no way to know into what name they were compiled or into what they may have been bound if created only temporarily for the purpose of binding.

Answer (score 0):

Using System i Navigator, expand Databases.  Right click on your system database. Select  SQL Plan Cache->  Show Statements.   From here, you can filter based on a variety of criteria.

Comment: Thanks, but cant find all sql executed here It seems that it is temporarily stored here in SQL Plan Cache

Answer (score 0):

This is not sure-fire, but often saves me some time. Using System i Navigator, right-click on the table and choose Index Advisor. If you're lucky, one or more indexes are advised. If so, sort by date last advised and right click on the index with the newest date and select Show Statements... In that dialog box, either sort by date to help narrow things down or just scroll through the statements to find the one you're interested in. Right-click it and select Work with SQL Statement and there you go.